# DJI M210 calibrate front stereo cameras for depth perception

Tags: c++, opencv3.0, dji-sdk

I'm trying to get the calibration values to put in the m210_stereo_param.yaml, like it's suggested in the official developer website ([OnboardSDK for Linux](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/sample-doc/advanced-sensing-stereo-depth-perception.html)). The objective is to have good values to test the depth perception sample. The website suggest different approach for the calibration, and I chose the OpenCV one.

I found an example of calibration on this Github repository: [Opencv - stereo_calibrate_rc](https://github.com/ruchirchauhan/Opencv/tree/master/stereo_calibrate_rc) (some explanations are given on this link: [Stereo Camera Calibration in Opencv 3](https://ruchirchauhan.wordpress.com/tag/stereo-calibration/))

The problem is that after getting the final Matrix (in the intrinsics.yaml and extrinsics.yaml), I modified the values in the m210_stereo_param.yaml, and tried to run the sample. I got this result (which is not correct, even the default values of the m210_stereo_param.yaml had a better result).

[image: screenshot of the depth perception sample running]

Do you have any idea of what is going wrong with the calibration ? It's quite complicated to found a clear approach to get values to put in the yaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve, the problem was that the xml file containing the list of images need to looks like this :

```
   "data/left01.jpg"
   "data/right01.jpg"
   "data/left02.jpg"
   "data/right02.jpg"
   "data/left03.jpg"
   ...
```

And mine xml file was more like this :

```
   "data/left01.jpg"
   "data/left02.jpg"
   "data/left03.jpg"
   ...
   "data/right01.jpg"
   "data/right02.jpg"
```

So, if you use this example, check if your xml file alternate left-right pictures.

Answer (score -1):

I asked the the tech support of DJI and he told me that the M210 does not support the calibration. In this case, you should not have these problems. Just use the original one.